# Operations with empty set in python returning null set

Tags: python, null, set, list-comprehension

```
b = set([j-i for j in set([1,2,3,4,5]) for i in set() if j-i>=0])

print b
```

Output:

```
set()
```

Why does this expression return an empty set instead of returning `set([1,2,3,4,5])` or raising an Error?

Comment: What were you expecting `for i in set()` to do?

Comment: Incidentally, an analogous set comprehension in mathematics would also be interpreted as an empty set - it's not just Python doing things this way.

Answer (score 1):

`for i in set()` is iterated zero times, leading to an empty set.

Comment: But isn't j still iterating? So shouldn't the minimum value be that of j?

Comment: And which value should `i` have?

Comment: @UtkarshAgrawal: Each element of `b` would have to correspond to an `(i, j)` pair, of which there are none. It doesn't matter that `j` values exist, because there are no `i` values to match them up with.

Comment: @user2357112 Oh! I get it now. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are iterating over zero items.  Unrolling the loops makes it clearer:

```
result = set()
for j in set([1,2,3,4,5]):
    for i in set():   #  <-- there are no i's !
        if j - i >= 0:
            result.add(j - i)
```

The code path to `add` to the `result` set can never be reached.